# Angular adding a row dynamically

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I am trying to create a new row.

I am trying to add a new objective in my form, which again has steps, when I create a new objective , then I go ahead and create a new step.

but when I go ahead and create a new objective it displays the step I created for the earlier objective. I am having issues creating steps in the form.
can someone please point me in the right direction?

the link is below
[**stackblitz link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4nlnoz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I readed your code. First of all to clarify yourself you should try to keep your variable name near their real meaning. For exemple  stepsArray is a good name but fieldArray should be called objectiveArray.

Secondly about your code structure. As I can see you can have "many objective" and those objective can have "many steps". Your model should "reflect" this.  So in your code you should have only one array, a array of objective :

Like this : An objective have a name and a list of steps.

```
objectives: Array<{name : string, steps: Array<any>}> = [];
```

I typed steps of Array of any but it could be more typed

```
Array<{ wwmonitor : string, hwmonitor : string, ...>}
```

How to add an objective ?   (old addFieldValue)

```
addNewObjective() {
      this.objectives.push({ name : '', steps : []});
  }
```

How to add a step ?

```
  addStepsValue(objective) {      
      objective.steps.push({}); 
  }
```

I let you imagine for "delete" :D

Manage your html :

```
      <table>
        <tbody *ngFor='let objective of objectives; let i = index'>
          <tr>
            <td>Objective</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td >
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control py-2 " type="text" [(ngModel)]="objective.name" [attr.name]="'objective'-i">

                <span class="g-float-right">
                    <button (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)">delete obj</button>
                </span>

                <span class="g-float-right">         
                     <button (click)="addStepsValue(objective)">add Steps</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover u-table--v1 mb-0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Step</th>
                    <th>Completion Date</th>
                    <th> Monitor</th>
                    <th>hmonitored?</th>
                    <th class="text-right">ACTION</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody  *ngFor='let step of objective.steps; let z = index'>
                  <tr >
                    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" [attr.id]="'fld1' + z" [(ngModel)]="step.actionstep"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0 form-control-sm" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" [(ngModel)]="step.date"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" type="text"[(ngModel)]="step.wwmonitor"></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" type="text"[(ngModel)]="step.hwmonitor"></td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button (click)="deleteStepsValue(objective, z)">delete steps</button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: Thank you  for your response.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have only one `stepsArray` and this is displayed for each objective. Your model should look like this:

```
objectives = [{
  name: string,
  steps: [
    actionstep: string,
    completionDate: Date,
    wwmonitor: string,
    hwmonitor: string
  ]
}]
```

when user clicks on add objective a new object should be pushed into objectives. When user clicks on add step a new object should be pushed into that objective steps. In the template you should iterate like this:

```
*ngFor="let objective of objectives
    display data for objective
    *ngFor="let step of objective.steps"
        display data for step
```